# google Cloud function :Error: memory limit exceeded. Function invocation was interrupted, but it works

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I created a new python google function that schedule a Query in BigQuery every 10 minutes, I test it and it works.

- deployment works fine
- testing give this error : Error: memory limit exceeded. logs not available ( but I can see that the Query did run as expected in BigQuery)
- using http trigger in cloud scheduler, I got failure with this the error message status: 503, but again, I can see in BigQuery console, it is running as expected

edit : here the code for the function

```
from google.cloud import bigquery


    def load(request):
        client = bigquery.Client()
        dataset_id = 'yyyyyyyy'
        table_id='xxxxxxxxxxx'
        job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
        job_config.use_legacy_sql = False
        table_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id).table(table_id)
        job_config.destination = table_ref
        job_config.write_disposition = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE
        sql = """
            SELECT * FROM `xxxxxx.datastudio.today_view`;
        """
    
        query_job = client.query(sql,location='asia-northeast1',job_config=job_config)
        query_job.result()
        print("Job finished.")
```

Comment: Can you add some example code of this cloud function?

Comment: I added the code, please notice the code works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BigQuery job is asynchronous. Your Cloud Function trigger it and wait up to completion. If the function fail between, it's not a problem, the 2 services aren't correlated.

If you do this by API, when you create a job (a query) you got immediately a JobID. Then you have to poll regularly this job ID to know its status. The client library do exactly the same!

Your out of memory issue come from the result which [wait the completion and read the results](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.result). Set a page size or a max_result to limit the data returned.

But, you can also don't wait the end and exit immediately (skip the line `query_job.result()`). You will save Cloud Functions processing (useless wait) time, and thus money!

Comment: I am using the same code in other function and it works just fine

Comment: I get this error when I removed query_job.result()     <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>

Comment: You don't have a return. add `return 'job running',200` at the end to exit gracefully. format: `return <response content>, <HTTP code>`